# Suggestion on how to implement conditional dependency?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I have two classes implementing the interfaces. Both the classes execute place search functionalities. Also in both the classe constructor there is a common functionality depending on the classes

Google : IGoogle

```
public NearBySearch(IWebPortalApiClient webPortalApiClient)
    {
        var serverString = ConfigHelper.GetAppSetting(ConfigConstants.APIServerType);
        var server = (WebPortalServer)Enum.Parse(typeof(WebPortalServer), serverString, true);
        this._webPortalApiClient = webPortalApiClient;
        this.GoogleKey = $"&key={ConfigHelper.GetAppSetting(ConfigConstants.Googlekey)}";
        this._webPortalApiClient.Init(server);
    }
```

Yelp : IYelp

```
public BusinessSearch(IWebPortalApiClient webPortalApiClient)
    {
        var serverString = ConfigHelper.GetAppSetting(ConfigConstants.APIServerType);
        var server = (WebPortalServer)Enum.Parse(typeof(WebPortalServer), serverString, true);
        this._webPortalApiClient = webPortalApiClient;
        this._webPortalApiClient.AccessToken = ConfigHelper.GetAppSetting(ConfigConstants.YelpApiKey);
        this._webPortalApiClient.Init(server, this._webPortalApiClient.AccessToken);
    }
```

In case of google we have to send key as a query parameter where as in Yelp we have to send key as Authorization header

In API Controller I am injecting Both

IGoogle

```
private IYelpController _yelpController;
    private IGoogleController _googleController;

    public PlaceSearchController(IYelpController yelpController, IGoogleController googleController)
    {
        this._yelpController = yelpController;
        this._googleController = googleController;
    }
```

The function that we are callin in API is like

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllBusiness(int web, decimal latitude, decimal longitude, string radius = null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (web == (int)PlaceSearch.Yelp)
            {
                var result = await _yelpController.GetAllBusiness(latitude, longitude, radius);
                var response = new Response<Common.Models.Yelp.Yelp>(ResponseConstants.Success, ResponseConstants.SuccessMessage, result);
                return Ok(response);
            }
            else if(web == (int)PlaceSearch.Google)
            {
                if(radius == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                var result = await _googleController.GetAllNearByPlaces(latitude, longitude, radius);
                var response = new Response<Common.Models.Google.Google>(ResponseConstants.Success, ResponseConstants.SuccessMessage, result);
                return Ok(response);
            }

            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var response = new Response<Object>(ResponseConstants.Forbidden, ResponseConstants.FailureMessage, null);
            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
```

The issue I am facing is below function is called in both the constructor

```
public IWebPortalApiClient Init(WebPortalServer server, string accessToken = null)
    {
        WebPortalServer = server;
        AccessToken = accessToken;
        return this;
    }
```

When Yelp is executed asses token is passed which is as expected but at the same time we dont pass access token in Google which sets the access token to null.

Because of this issue I am not able to call Yelp API as it does not find the access token.

Is there a way that we inject dependency on conditional basis. We are using Unity Container for this.

Web Portal Client

```
public class WebPortalApiClient : IWebPortalApiClient
{
    public WebPortalServer WebPortalServer { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    private string ServerUrl
    {
        get
        {
            switch (WebPortalServer)
            {
                case WebPortalServer.Dev:
                    return null;
                case WebPortalServer.QA:
                    return null;
                case WebPortalServer.Demo:
                    return null;
                case WebPortalServer.Production:
                    return null;
                case WebPortalServer.Localhost:
                    return "http://localhost:63695/";
                case WebPortalServer.Integration:
                    return null;
                case WebPortalServer.UAT:
                    return null;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<HttpContent> InvokeApi(string path, HttpAction action, HttpContent content = null, TimeSpan? overrideTimeout = null, string externalServer = null)
    {

        var sUrl = externalServer == null ? ServerUrl : externalServer;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(sUrl);
            if (overrideTimeout.HasValue)
            {
                client.Timeout = overrideTimeout.Value;
            }
            //this.Log("Connecting to {0} Api at {1}".Fmt(WebPortalServer, ServerUrl));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", AccessToken);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            switch (action)
            {
                case HttpAction.Get:
                    response = await client.GetAsync(path);
                    break;
                case HttpAction.Post:
                    response = await client.PostAsync(path, content);
                    break;
                case HttpAction.Put:
                    response = await client.PutAsync(path, content);
                    break;
                case HttpAction.Delete:
                    response = await client.DeleteAsync(path);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("action", action, null);
            }

            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? response.Content : null;
        }
    }

    public IWebPortalApiClient Init(WebPortalServer server, string accessToken = null)
    {
        WebPortalServer = server;
        AccessToken = accessToken;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without [MCVE] which includes your Unity registration it is very hard to see how you endup with single instance of `IWebPortalApiClient` for your two classes... probably someone set it up to be per-request instead of per-invocation... or some other lifetime mismatch.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov added Web Portal Client Class code